# Import Specific fields from .csv to SQL Serverl using File Upload in Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, csv

csv file that has 20 columns,i have uploaded that using FileUpload Control, now i want to add only one column data in database from that 20 columns, how can i achieve this..
my code is-

```
    DataTable tblReadCSV = new DataTable();
    tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("EmailId");
    string path = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fupEmails.PostedFile.FileName);
    fupEmails.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Contacts/" + path));
    path = Server.MapPath("~/Contacts/" + path);
    TextFieldParser csvParser = new TextFieldParser(path);
    csvParser.Delimiters = new string[] { "," };
    csvParser.TrimWhiteSpace = true;
    //csvParser.ReadLine();
    while (!csvParser.EndOfData)
    {
        string[] fields = csvParser.ReadFields();
        tblReadCSV.Rows.Add(fields.);
    }
    string connection = @"Data Source=ANURAG-PC; Initial Catalog=MailServer; Persist Security Info=True; User ID=xx; Password=xxxxxx";
    string strSql = "Insert into EmailData(EmailId) Values(@Email)";
    SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(connection);
    SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType=CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText=strSql;
    cmd.Connection=con;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email",SqlDbType.NVarChar,250,"EmailId");
    SqlDataAdapter daAdapter=new SqlDataAdapter();
    daAdapter.InsertCommand=cmd;
    int result=daAdapter.Update(tblReadCSV);
    lblError.Text="Send Successfully";
```

and the problem is in these three lines-

```
while (!csvParser.EndOfData)
{
    string[] fields = csvParser.ReadFields();
    tblReadCSV.Rows.Add(fields.Equals("Email");
}
```

here fields contains all the column headings so i just want only one field Email from the whole,how can i achieve this, above lines are not working for this.

Comment: I don't think it is wise to post (in your connection string) your username and password on the internet.  Even if it is on SO.  I have 'x'd' them out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `DataRow` that matches the schema of you data table, and then insert the correct value from your parsed line of CSV values into that row, and then add the row to the `DataTable`. Roughly something like the following

```
while (!csvParser.EndOfData)
{
    var fields = csvParser.ReadFields();
    var row = tblReadCSV.NewRow();
    row["EmailId"] = fields[ordinalPositionOfEmailField];
    tblReadCSV.Rows.Add(row)
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your suggestion but it is same as my previous code, it is also adding the first row which is the heading of the columns in csv file, i dont want the first row.

Comment: Your previous code doesn't compile. Also you can skip the first line by reading once before entering the loop...

Answer (score 0):

Put following line before your while loop

```
var FirstRowfields = csvParser.ReadFields();
while(!csvParser.EndOfData)
{
  //your code
}
```

This will read first line and then start your loop will start reading from second line so you will not heading column